# How do I upgrade multisite drupal 6 to 7

Tags: drupal

I have a drupal 6 multisite setup on my local server. I  want to upgrade these sites to drupal 7 as some of the modules have not been converted to drupal 7 yet.

What is the high-level process I should follow?

Answer (score 1):

1. Create a copy of the codebase.
2. Delete the configurations for the sites that you don't want to upgrade from the copy.
3. Configure your webserver so that the sites you want to upgrade point to the copy.
4. Delete the configurations for the sites that you want to upgrade from the original.
5. Upgrade the copy as usual.